# When I open my gmail account,this shows,does this mean my account is hacked?

Tags: intrusion

When I open my gmail acccount I see a dialogue box that reads
like shown in the image?Does it mean my account is hacked?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This occurs because you're viewing an email that contains images and other resources served over HTTP, whilst the connection to the gmail site itself is HTTPS. This is known as mixed-mode, and it's risky in cases where an attacker can perform a man-in-the-middle attack. In this case, I don't think you should worry about it - it's completely normal to get this warning if you have embedded images enabled in emails.

Comment: gmail loads external images by default? WTF

Comment: @CodesInChaos No, it doesn't. You either have to opt-in (per sender or globally), or click "Show images" on the email each time you load it.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad I can't read the other question, since I don't have a Quora account. We discourage cross-posting here, which is likely why you got a downvote on this question. Regardless, I have seen absolutely no evidence that your gmail account has been compromised.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad He's talking about gmail's default image loading policy on emails. And no, they don't load images by default.

Comment: I have deleted the comments that are entirely offtopic.